# Resize Highcharts StockChart range selector to lessthan 6 data points

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I resize chart using highstock range selector to select less than 6 points.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xybmmg9b/) is what I did. You can check there, we can resize range selector but can't select less than 6 data points.
Is there any option to specify minimum number of data points should be selected?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts("StockChart", {

    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: There is no point limit in axis range, but there is a minRange explained in the answer below - it depends on axis unit range and by default is calculated from distance between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the XAxis : minRange value, and give it a value in milliseconds, eg for one month

```
xAxis: {
        minRange: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }
```

Seeing 6 datapoints is because that is the default value, see [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange)